# how to unit-test c# reactivex.io

Tags: c#, reactivex

im trying to write unit tests for a class that is written using reactivex.io .

my test code is something like this:

```js
 [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string userName = "Moeen";
            string password = "moeen123";
            string instrument = "Bass";

            _loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();
            _loggerMock.Setup(x => x.RequestInput(Messages.EnterUsername)).Returns(Observable.Return(userName));
            _loggerMock.Setup(x => x.RequestInput(Messages.EnterPassword)).Returns(Observable.Return(password));
            // _loggerMock.Setup(x => x.ShowProgressIndicator("loading")).Returns(ValueFunction);
            var options = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Instrument)).Cast<Instrument>().Select(val => val.ToString());
            _loggerMock.Setup(x => x.RequestInput($"{Messages.SelectInstrument} [{string.Join("|", options)}]")).Returns(Observable.Return(instrument));
            _loggerMock.Setup(x => x.ShowMessage(""));


            _backendMock = new UnreliableFakeBackend();


         

            var result = new SignupFlow(_backendMock, _loggerMock.Object).Run();


            result.Subscribe(x =>
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(true,false);
            });
```

I tested it but the  **Assert** code never gets called inside the **subscribe** function so the function always asserts true.

as I read the  [docs](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#TestingRx) I have to write a scheduler to make it work but it doesn't explain well enough to make it work.

Comment: Why you don't also mock the IObservable?

Comment: @Max don't understand what you mean!

Comment: You can mock the `IObservable<Unit>` like this `var ob = new Mock<IObservable<Unit>>`, setup the required methods of the IObservable, and return it  on `_backendMock.Setup`